# How to retrieve the cycle time of each processor in the system?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, windows-kernel

I'm planning to use `QueryThreadCycleTime()` to in order to calculate the percentage of CPU  some specific thread has used during a given interval (between two samples).

The main issue is I need to know how many CPU cycles (in total) have elapsed between the two samples :

```
QueryThreadCycleTime(threadId, &threadCycleTime);
QueryTotalCPUCycleTime(&totalCPUTime); //does not exists

cpuUsage = (threadCycleTime - previousThreadCycleTime) / (totalCPUTime - previousCPUTime) * 100;

previousThreadCycleTime = threadCycleTime;
previousCPUTime= totalCPUTime;
```

One possibility would be to loop on all threads and sum up their cycle time (based on difference with previous sample), but the major issue is not all of can be opened (additionally, most systems have thousands of threads).

Another is to read RDTSC. Unfortunately this will only return the amount of CPU cycles for the current CPU, not all.

I don't want to use `GetThreadTimes()` because (based on my own experiments and what I read about it) it does not report any CPU usage unless threads as used at least one quantum (15 ms on my system). If a thread use CPU sporadically (eg: goes into wait state before quantum has elapsed) nothing will be reported.

Comment: A CPU is not dedicated to a single program.  Other cores could be busy executing code from entirely different programs.  That's why you can't find a winapi function that gives you this info.

Comment: The winapi function I gave as example is simplified. Typically you would an array of cycle times (one for each CPU). Something similar to the `QueryIdleProcessorCycleTime()` function (which really exists).

Comment: You could use `QueryIdleProcessorCycleTime function` to retrieve the cycle time for the idle thread of each processor in the system.

If you want to retrieve the cycle time for each processor in the system, as far as I'm concerned, there is no suitable api, the reason is that the number of CPU cycles required to execute an instruction depends on the architecture of the CPU itself and there's no straightforward one-to-one relationship.

Comment: The main issue with `QueryIdleProcessorCycleTime` is that it does not include cycles spent on some other threads. So reported CPU usage will be higher than what it is. I am not sure to understand your remark about the fact such api could not exists. Using CPU cycles to measure things has many caveats, especially with modern CPUs, but I don't see what would prevent the OS to have a function that to loop on all CPUs and retrieve RDTSC register for each of them.